# fetch data from different localhost in Angular

Tags: angular

in Angular, `ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0` creates an instance of http server. I've been told, that in order to fetch data from server side scripts in Angular, another localhost is needed.

In ngOnInit I fetch the data:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/echo.php').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);      
    });
  }
```

This fetch has a status code `200` in `Network tab of Developer tools` but I am getting a CORS error in the console:

```
Failed to load http://localhost/echo.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It appears that differenr ports cause this. What should I do to prevent that? Browser itself has no issue by fetching this file, it is Angular that complains.

UPDATE: I've followed the suggestions and came up with a new error. this time it is: `GET http://localhost:4200/backend/echo.php 504 (Gateway Timeout)`

the "other" server is configured to listen to port 80 with `DocumentRoot` being `backend ..`

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/backend/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/backend/echo.php').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);      
    });
  }
```

file structure:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Comment: It has nothing to do with Angular. This is a core feature of the browser's JavaScript security.

Comment: @Quentin I think it can be related with Angular. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer .

Comment: @Pac0 — It is related to Angular only in so far as Angular is written in JavaScript. That URL doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: i tried this to see if it will work. but it does not. if you are using WAMP, you can use Directory tag in apache's httpd.conf if your URL files are in a folder, or LocationMatch if it is another domain. I use that technique to be able to  run from angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proxy your application on http://localhost by creating a file called `proxy.conf.json` in your angular project with the following content:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

and then starting `ng serve` with the additional parameter `--proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

```
ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

You have to change your call then to include the port and  `/api` prefix:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api/echo.php').subscribe(data => {
...
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/d22e9ae73763923980fc1e59cfb2a0bf255b98d8/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/HackPoint/ng-apps my repository I do it the same way

Comment: thanks. Now I am getting 504 (Gateway Timeout) error in the console and network tab :)

Comment: The final probelm was that `http://localhost` needes to be replaced with `http://127.0.0.1`. After that, this solution works.

Answer (score 3):

If you have **Tow loalhost** application, first is Angular app and is running in **http://localhost:4200** and another is API project and running in **http://localhost:3000**,  In this situation if from your angular app make request to another, you get CORS error, for solving this problem you can use below instructions step by step:

1. Make a file and name it **proxy.config.json** inside main folder of Angular project like below image:

[image: Angular Project Structure]

2. Then put codes **inside** created file like this (please notice to target part):

   ```
   {
       "/api/*": {
           "target": "http://localhost:3000",
           "secure": false,
           "logLevel": "debug"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then Change **package.josn** file and insert code like below image"

[image: Package.json file Inside]

4. And after all you must use **npm start** to running anglar project

> Note: If you don't do it for angular project, you will occure with CORS problem.