# After adding proxy.config.json still 404 page error in angular 4 and node+express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express

I'm getting server side response. If I try with url http://localhost:3000/api/projectsList. If i'm trying to call same using proxy.config.json with angular 4 service url http://localhost:4200/bootstrap-table it is showing me 404 error. [Success page from Node server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N09Gp.png) , [Error from angular service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czG78.png) , [API call from angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMYYZ.png)

Comment: how are you adding the proxy config?

Comment: {
    "/api/*":{
      "target":"http://localhost:3000",
      "secure":false,
      "logLevel":"debug"
    }
  }

Comment: As Sania suggested I[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608247/fetch-data-from-different-localhost-in-angular/47612832#47612832) have followed:

Comment: can you add the content of the file to post